# C Compiler cannot create Executables on Mac OS Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, gcc, rbenv

I've been through almost every page and all the tips don't fix the problem. I'm running Mountain Lion I've got Xcode, all the latest developer tools the latest GCC and everything. I am trying to set up rbenv and ruby-build. Everything seems to work but when I go to install a version of ruby it says that the c compiler doesn't work and that it can't create executables.  The exact last lines of the log:

```
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/zr/gv4jcc_122sfrtpfj5g9prc00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130106144331.1477/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I'm stumped. The log contains:

```
configure:3265: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2  -I'/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Users/jmart/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/include'  -L'/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Users/jmart/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib'  conftest.c  >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: HD: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: 2/Users/jmart/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/include': No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: HD: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: 2/Users/jmart/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib': No such file or directory
configure:3269: $? = 1
configure:3307: result: no
```

UPDATE:: Noticing the "HD: No such..." & "2" No Such... I do have two two Drives installed in my mac - one for user files and one for sys files. Is that what's throwing the error here?

Comment: There should be a `config.log` file generated. Look in there for more information.

Comment: http://chopapp.com/#w2ag3an8

Comment: That file has the log - I always hate pouring through pages of log outputs in user forums.

Comment: Well just post the relevant part, not too hard to find in this case. Looks like the script can't handle spaces in paths.

Comment: Yah, just saw that - it's been a problem before. Is there a way to safely rename the HD without erasing the volume? I'm trying to tell which script is throwing the error to see if I can manually adjust it but I can't quite tell - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in the configure script, but there is no need to rename the volume; just make a symbolic link. I don't have a Mac, but something like this should do it (as root):

```
cd /Volumes
ln -s 'Macintosh HD2' MacHD2
```

Then:

```
./configure --prefix=/Volumes/MacHD2/Users/jmart/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces must be escaped.

```
$ pwd
/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/userdata/...
```

Typing `cd` and copy-pasting :

```
$ cd /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/userdata
-bash: cd: /Volumes/VMware: No such file or directory
$ cd /Volumes/VMware\ Shared\ Folders/userdata/
...:userdata ba$
```

In case of `cd`, using tab completion automatically adds the backslash-space.

Comment: Right, and I get that - but the problem is that I don't know where to force that in the script. I don't have control over the path or at least not knowing where that path is pulling from. I can manually compile ruby versions into the dir because I can specify my path - any idea how to manipulate the compiler path so I can escape the spaces?

Comment: I'm new to OS X and can't help much. I had a look at rbenv home page, but didn't like it (if I well remember, you need to compile). I use RVM, had a problem at installation, have some difficulties finding answers in the doc, but at least I have easily installed several rubies (just install, no compilation) and it's so easy to switch from one to another, and install gems inside an isolated gemset. I have just found this comparison : http://jonathan-jackson.net/rvm-and-rbenv