# Ruby install fails because the path to download location has a space and cd fails

Tags: ruby, installation, space

When installing Ruby, I get an error because it tries to cd into a path that starts with `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/...` and fails because of the space after Macintosh. How can change the location to something without a space or otherwise fix this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182791/c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-on-mac-os-mountain-lion/14192226#14192226

Comment: What is the command you try to install ruby with?

Comment: I just got rid of the space in the hard drive's name, it was giving me some other issues as well. thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the quotes around the path help, or a backslash before the space.

"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/..."

or

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/...
```

Comment: But I never specify this address, it's part of the process that goes on by itself for the installation. Is there maybe an option flag I can pass to the install command to change the address?